# Preencher um campo através da seleção de outro campo

Tags: php, mysqli, formulário

Tenho um formulário de pedidos onde é escolhido o nome do cliente e gostaria que a partir dessa seleção fosse preenchido o campo de desconto, esse valor está na mesma tabela onde fica o cadastro do cliente.

Como posso fazer o campo de desconto ser preenchido a partir da escolha do cliente?

meu select está assim:

```
    $qr2=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM `clientes` order by `nome`");
if (mysqli_num_rows($qr2)==0)
    echo "Adicione ao menos um Cliente";
```

o campo no formulário onde é escolhido o cliente está assim:

```
    <strong><b><font size="3"> <font color="#000000">Cliente :</strong>
<select name="clienteAt">  <option value="">Selecione o Cliente</option>
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qr2)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['nome']?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

e o campo de desconto está assim:

```
<td>
 <input name="desconto[]" type="text" required name="desconto"
  maxlength="30" size="11" onblur="Calc(this)"
  style="text-align:center"
  class="desconto" />
</td>
```

Comment: Use javascript.

Comment: Você pode guardar os dados de desconto dos clientes num array js e usar lógica para setar o valor no input

Answer (score 1):

Vou tentar passar mais ou menos a ideia do que você pode fazer.

1 - Quando selecionar um cliente no seu comboBox crie uma requisição ajax para uma outra página ex: getDescontoCliente.php com o id do cliente selecionado.

2- Na página getDescontoCliente.php pegue o id através de um $_GET e faça sua seleção de desconto na sua base de dados.

3 - Da um ECHO no valor de desconto na mesma página.

4 - pegue o retorno da requisição ajax feita na página do comboBox e preenche o input com esse retorno.

Passei mas a ideia do que você pode fazer.